# For each node found an XML but not deleting?

Tags: xml, vb.net, nodes

I have an xml file with the same structure as the following:

```
<Index>
  <Id>Jack</Id>
  <Id>Frank</Id>
  <Id>Bob</Id>
</Index>
```

What I want is to check the nodes inner text and if it equals a particular value say "Frank" that it deletes that node. What I have tried is the following:

```
Dim MyDoc as xmlDocument = new xmlDocument()
MyDoc.load("C:\my.xml")

For Each Node as XmlNode in MyDoc.selectNodes("Index/*")
  If Node.InnerText=("Frank") Then
    Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(Node)
  End If
Next

Mydoc.save("C:\my.xml")
```

If I swap out `Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(Node)` for `MsgBox(node.InnerText)` I see that I do indeed find the node With Frank as its inner text. From my understanding `Node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(Node)` means go to the Parent of the current Node then to the child of that parent should remove the node `<Id>` with the inner text "Frank" whilst retaining all the other Nodes name `<Id>`. However it still is found in the XML file when I open it up in notepad. I also tried using remove all, remove parent and remove child but I can't get it to delete.

Comment: I tried your code and it works as you described, it deletes the middle node from the file, maybe I misunderstood your issue.

Comment: Hmm strange I ran it a good 20x yesterday and it refused to takeout the <id>Frank </id> node hens why I posted it. ... I think I might just try the code in a blank new project without all the other code see if it will work then